# Is there a R function equivalent to the subset operator `[ ]`, in order to slice by index?

Tags: r, vector, slice

I know that `[]` is a function itself, but is there a function that does the following ?

```r
vect = c(1, 5, 4)

# Slicing by row index with []
vect[2]
# [1] 5

# Does this kind of function exist ? 
slicing_func(vect, 2)
# [1] 5

# And for dataframes ?
```

Comment: `getElement` also works on data.frame

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `getElement` function

```
vect = c(1, 5, 4)

getElement(vect, 2)

#> 5
```

Or you can use

```
vctrs::vec_slice(vect , 2)

#> 5
```

which works for slices and data.frames too.

Comment: Note that `vctrs::vec_slice(vect , 2:3)` works but not `getElement(vect, 2:3)`

Answer (score 9):

To understand the deeper meaning of *"`[]` is actually a function"* —

```
vect[2]
# [1] 5
```

is equivalent to:

```
`[`(vect, 2)
# [1] 5
```

Seems you have already used the function you are looking for.

**Note,** that it also works for data frames/matrices.

```
dat
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  1  4  7 10
# 2  2  5  8 11
# 3  3  6  9 12

`[`(dat, 2, 3)
# [1] 8

`[`(dat, 2, 3, drop=F)  ## to get a data frame back
#   X3
# 2  3
```

---

*Data:*

```
vect <- c(1, 5, 4)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
```

Comment: I already stated that I knew that it was a function, it's just not pretty to write a function with backticks

Comment: @Julien This is a matter of taste, you could do `foo <- \`[\`; foo(vect, 2)` or use a fancy package that sells the trick as ingenious function.

Comment: Please add `foo <- `[`; foo(vect, 2)` in your answer

Comment: But I will not accept it as the answer still

Comment: dplyr also has the `nth` function which works on vectors and data.frames. Similar to getElement

Comment: I tried `dplyr::nth(vect, 2:3)` and got an error

Comment: `dplyr::nth(vect, 2)` works though

Comment: @Julien So your question actually is: "Is there another function which does the same as `[` but is called differently?"?

Answer (score 3):

For a data frame you can use `slice`:

```r
library(dplyr)
vect = c(1, 5, 4)
vect %>% as.data.frame() %>% slice(2)
#>   .
#> 1 5
nth(vect, 2)
#> [1] 5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

`slice` according to documentation:

> slice() lets you index rows by their (integer) locations. It allows
> you to select, remove, and duplicate rows.

Comment: I can't accept this answer since I'm looking for a function that applies on vectors

Comment: Hi @Julien, The output is actually `5`.

Comment: And that outputs a vector

Answer (score 2):

We could use `pluck` or `chuck` from `purrr` package:

- pluck() and chuck() implement a generalised form of [[ that allow you to index deeply and flexibly into data structures. pluck() consistently returns NULL when an element does not exist, chuck() always throws an error in that case.

```
library(purrr)

pluck(vect, 2)
chuck(vect, 2)

> pluck(vect, 2)
[1] 5
> chuck(vect, 2)
[1] 5
```

Comment: note that pluck() and chuck()  can't slice vectors.

Comment: Yes. -> But it answers the question! -> Pluck or chuck a **single element from** a vector or environment